# How to get rid of NA in my vector

Tags: r

I have a vector as follows:

```
> dput(v)
structure(c("1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "2", "2", "1", "2", 
"2", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "2", 
"1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "1", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
"NA", "NA", "2", "1", "2", "2", "1", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "1", "2", "2", 
"1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", "2", 
"1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", 
"2", "2", "2", "1", "2", "2", "1", "1", "2", "2", "1", "1", "2", 
"1", "2", "1", "2", "2", "1", "2", "1", "1", "2", "2", "1", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "2", "2", "1"), .Label = logical(0))
```

I want to get rid of the NAs, so I've tried `na.omit`, which didn't work. I think the NAs are not of type NA, but are literally the character string "NA" so I tried to convert them to type NA with the following

```
v[] <- lapply(v, function(x) {
    is.na(levels(x)) <- levels(x) == "NA"
    x
})
```

Which didn't work the way I wanted it to.

---

*Edit

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(w = c(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 
1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 
2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), x = c("1", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2", 
"1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "1", 
"1", "2", "1", "2", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "2", "1", "1", "NA", 
"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "1", "1", "2", 
"2", "1", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "1", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "2", "2", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "2", "1", 
"1", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2", 
"2", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "2", "2", "1", "2", "2", 
"1", "1", "2", "2", "1", "2", "2", "1", "1", "2", "2", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "1", "2", "1"), y = c("1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "2", 
"2", "1", "2", "2", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "1", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "1", "2", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", 
"1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "2", "1", "2", "2", "1", "2", "2", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "1", 
"2", "2", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "1", 
"1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", 
"2", "1", "2", "2", "2", "1", "2", "2", "1", "1", "2", "2", "1", 
"1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "2", "1", "2", "1", "1", "2", "2", 
"1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "2", "2", "1"), 
    z = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1", "2"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("w", 
"x", "y", "z"), row.names = c(11L, 12L, 14L, 16L, 19L, 20L, 24L, 
29L, 30L, 34L, 36L, 38L, 41L, 42L, 44L, 63L, 66L, 69L, 74L, 76L, 
78L, 80L, 81L, 91L, 93L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 103L, 104L, 106L, 109L, 
117L, 118L, 120L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 129L, 133L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 13L, 15L, 17L, 18L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 25L, 
26L, 27L, 28L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 35L, 37L, 39L, 40L, 43L, 45L, 46L, 
47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 
60L, 61L, 62L, 64L, 65L, 67L, 68L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 75L, 77L, 
79L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 92L, 94L, 95L, 
99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 105L, 107L, 108L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 
114L, 115L, 116L, 119L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 127L, 128L, 130L, 131L, 
132L, 134L), class = "data.frame")
```

Given such  data.frame, I want to delete any row with NA in it. I've tried `ld` from `ForImp` package, but that doesn't work since the "NA"s are not of type NA.

Comment: What if I have a data.frame and I wish to do a list-wise deletion of any rows that contain "NA"? I am editing my original question now

Comment: you're moving the goalposts a little bit ... make sure you post a reproducible sample for your new question too ...

Comment: I have edited my original post with reproducible sample. The reason why I wanted to convert them to type NA first is so that I can use the `ld` function to perform a list-wise deletion in my data.frame.

Comment: PS what do you mean by "list-wise deletion"? (I'm not going to go and look up the `ForImp` package to find out ...)

Comment: Delete any row with NA in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my Note at the end of this.

#### Original object/vector

Your object seems somewhat odd; it's a character vector but it has an attribute `"levels"` which is a zero-length logical vector.

Anyway, you want to look for character strings `"NA"` here because those are literal `"NA"` strings not `NA`s.

```
xx[xx != "NA"]

> xx[xx != "NA"]
  [1] "1" "2" "2" "2" "2" "1" "2" "2" "1" "2" "2" "1" "1" "2" "2" "2" "1" "2"
 [19] "2" "2" "2" "1" "2" "1" "1" "2" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "2" "2" "1" "2" "2"
 [37] "2" "2" "2" "2" "2" "1" "2" "2" "1" "2" "2" "1" "1" "1" "1" "2" "2" "1"
 [55] "1" "1" "1" "1" "2" "2" "1" "2" "2" "1" "1" "2" "2" "2" "1" "1" "2" "2"
 [73] "2" "1" "1" "2" "1" "2" "1" "2" "1" "2" "1" "1" "1" "2" "1" "2" "1" "2"
 [91] "2" "2" "1" "2" "2" "1" "1" "2" "2" "1" "1" "2" "1" "2" "1" "2" "2" "1"
[109] "2" "1" "1" "2" "2" "1" "2" "2" "2" "2" "2" "2" "2" "1" "2" "2" "1"
```

(where `xx` is the object you posted).

#### Data frame example

Assuming your data frame is in `xxx` now, first find elements that are `"NA"`:

xxx != "NA"

Then compute the row sum, noting that `TRUE == 1` and `FALSE == 2` when doing so, and find rows with fewer than `ncol(xxx)` (i.e. 4) `TRUE` values.

```
ind <- rowSums(xxx != "NA") < ncol(xxx)
```

(@DavidArenburg suggests the alternative `rowSums(xxx == "NA") > 0` which is somewhat more succinct than the version above and certainly more succinct than my original.)

This indicates the rows with at least one `"NA"` **string**

Then use `ind` to deselect those rows of `xxx`:

```
XXX <- xxx[!ind, ]

> XXX <- xxx[!ind, ]
> nrow(xxx)
[1] 134
> nrow(XXX)
[1] 125
```

#### Note:

I will add that like `xx`, `xxx` (your data frame) is also a bit odd:

```
> str(xxx)
'data.frame':   134 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ w: num  2 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 ...
 $ x: chr  "1" "2" "2" "2" ...
 $ y: chr  "1" "2" "2" "2" ...
 $ z: Factor w/ 3 levels "0","1","2": 2 1 3 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 ..
```

It almost seems as though you've combined three different kinds of object all with apparently values 0, 1, 2, but which are actually subtly different objects. You also seem to have `"NA"` strings where you probably wanted `NA`s. I'd look into why and how you ended up with such a data frame.

Comment: Thank you. This helped a lot. Well my colleague gave me a set of data she put together in excel...I'm not savvy with excel so I don't know how this came about.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks!. Yup. I actually had a bunch of things like that but got distracted and never updated my Answer with the simpler construct.

Answer (score 2):

You moved the goalposts a little bit with your edit, but:

```
anyCharNA <- apply(dd,1,function(x) any(x=="NA"))
dim(dd)
## [1] 134   4
dim(dd[!anyCharNA,])
## [1] 125   4
```

notes:

- it can under certain (rare) circumstances be dangerous/confusing to call your data `data`, which is also the name of a built-in function.  R can usually tell the difference, but not always ...
- you might want to go back and change your workflow so that your data doesn't end up so weird and you can just use `na.omit()` ...

If instead you want to clean up your data -- assuming that you actually want everything to be an integer --

```
dd[] <- lapply(dd,function(x) as.integer(as.character(x)))
na.omit(dd)
```

(the extra complication is necessary to make sure that factors get converted back to integers correctly)

Comment: I think the safest way in such cases is to use `type.convert` as in `dd[] <- lapply(dd, function(x) type.convert(as.character(x)))` so you won't need to worry about classes.